# How to control translateX and translateY independently with javascript on the same object (no range input)?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to control an object position via transform/translate by using onclick events. The problem is that when I update translateX, it overwrites translateY and vice versa.
Is there any way to control them separately? I've read some stuff about CSS variables, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.
Please, if someone could help me I'll be very glad! Thanks!

```
function moveX() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
}
function moveY() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "translateY(100px)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work for sure

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "translate(20%,100%)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wasn't clear. The thing is I want to control X and Y independently. One button controls X and the other controls Y. The problem is after clicking the X button, clicking Y button resets X position and vice versa. It's not a "one movement" click, it's a two step movement. Like buttonX moves a DIV X-200px, buttonY moves Y-50px.
I want to move a DIV n-times up/down and after choosing this first option, move the DIV n-times left/right.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        :root {
            --tx: 0;
            --ty: 0;
        }

        .mask {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            transform: 
                translateX(var(--tx))
                translateY(var(--ty));
            background: yellow;
        }

        .one,
        .two {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .one{
            top: 0;
            background: orange;
        }

        .two{
            top: 100px;
            background: lime;
        }

        .elements {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 0 10px;
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mask">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="one">
                <div class="elements">1</div>
                <div class="elements">2</div>
                <div class="elements">3</div>
                <div class="elements">4</div>
                <div class="elements">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <div class="elements">A</div>
                <div class="elements">B</div>
                <div class="elements">C</div>
                <div class="elements">D</div>
                <div class="elements">E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- CHOOSE AN OPTION (CHOICES MOVES UP OR DOWN) -->
    <div>
        <button onclick="optionA()">Option A</button>
        <button onclick="optionB()">Option B</button>
    </div>

    <!-- INSIDE THE OPTION, CHOOSE A "SUB-OPTION" ("SUB-CHOICES") MOVES LEFT OR RIGHT -->
    <div>
        <button onclick="moveA()">A</button>
        <button onclick="moveB()">B</button>
        <button onclick="moveC()">C</button>
        <button onclick="moveD()">D</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        // MOVES UP AND DOWN
        function optionA() {document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateY(0)";}
        function optionB() {document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateY(-100px)";}

        // MOVES TO THE SIDE (RIGHT)
        function moveA() {document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(0)";}
        function moveB() {document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(40px)";}
        function moveC() {document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(80px)";}
        function moveD() {document.getElementById("container").style.transform = "translateX(120px)";}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: A code example would improve your answer's quality.